# Chart.Js pie chart click

Tags: chart.js

In `Chart.Js v3.3.2` docs, there is this sample to get information from the item you clicked in the chart.

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        onClick: (e) => {
            const canvasPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, chart);

            // Substitute the appropriate scale IDs
            const dataX = chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);
            const dataY = chart.scales.y.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.y);
        }
    }
});
```

This works for charts that have axis, like bar and line charts. But Pie charts don't have axis, so this code does not work.

How can I get the index of the slice I clicked in pie charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you could try the following approach:

```
 options:{
    ...
    onClick: pieChartClickEvent,
    ...
}

function pieChartClickEvent(event, array){
    if(array[0]){
        //do something 
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting, I can't find anything in the docs about that second argument you put after the event. But it really exists and it does have the index information.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're using Chart.js version 2, this can be done as follows:

```
onClick: evt => {
  var elements = pieChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
  var index = elements[0]._index;
  console.log(index)
}
```

> Please consult section [`.getElementsAtEvent(e)`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/developers/api.html#getelementsatevente) from Chart.js v2 documentation.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works:

```js
const pieChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [{      
      data: [8, 5, 6],
      backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    events: ['click', 'mousemove', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
    onClick: evt => {
      var elements = pieChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
      var index = elements[0]._index;
      console.log(index);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: My bad for not making it clear in the question that I'm using v3. This doesn't work in v3 but thanks for the answer.